# Municipal bonds investment tax for couple living in different states and file jointly

Tags: united-states, taxes, municipal-bonds

My spouse and I live in different states (my spouse in A, and I in B).
If my spouse buys muni-bond for state A and we file jointly at tax year end, is this investment federal and/or state tax free (supposedly tax free if we both live in A)?

Comment: Consult a tax adviser that is familiar with both states.  I imagine that it would very much depend upon the actual state in which the two of you reside for the correct answer.